# React Native, multiple ReactRootView?

Tags: react-native

We have a single ReactRootView now and planning to use more ReactRootView in other activities/viewControllers. 
(We are integrating RN into existing native app)

All the tutorials I've found just handles single ReactRootView.

- Question #1

> Should I create multiple "index.android" and "index.android.bundle"
>   files?

- Question #2

> Should I share `ReactInstanceManager`?

If it is good to share `ReactInstanceManager` and to have multiple `index.android` files, how could I go about changing the following codes?

```
   mReactInstanceManager = ReactInstanceManager.builder()
     .setApplication(getApplication())
     .setBundleAssetName("index.android.bundle")
     .setJSMainModuleName("index.android")
     .addPackage(new MainReactPackage())
     .addPackage(new SvgPackage())
     .addPackage(new VectorIconsPackage())
     .addPackage(new SearchFilterManagerPackage())
     .setUseDeveloperSupport(BuildConfig.DEBUG)
     .setInitialLifecycleState(LifecycleState.RESUMED)
     .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

> Question #1
>   Should I create multiple "index.android" and "index.android.bundle" files?

Although you could, you probably should not. You should have a single bundle file.

> Question #2
>   Should I share ReactInstanceManager?

Yes, you should share the *ReactInstanceManager* instance, typically through some kind of singleton object. Then, when you build your many ReactRootViews, you reference the same *ReactInstanceManager*